# Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\Section' not found

Tags: laravel, phpword

I am trying to add list item to phpword template with following code:

```
    $PHPWord = new PHPWord();
    $document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate(storage_path('app/template_report.docx'));
    
    $section = $PHPWord->addSection();
    $section->addListItem('List Item 1', 0);
    $section->addTextBreak(1);

    $document->setComplexBlock('list_items', $section);

    $save_file_name = storage_path('app/report_'.date('Ymd_His').'.docx');
    $document->saveAs($save_file_name);
```

but return following error:

> Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\Section' not found

Why its happend and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: you should `use` your class (PHPWord) above of your controller . then try again.

Comment: @AmirKhaledian, yes, i was add use PHPWord. The problem is, even when I check the source code, there was no PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\Section class at all in the PHPWord package.

Comment: Please, add the imports defined at the top of the file. Maybe, you're importing the wrong class. Also, specify the version of the package you're using (check that out in the composer.json)

Comment: This class never existed in the code, if you look in the [Master branch on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/master/src/PhpWord/Writer/Word2007/Element), even in older version this class doesn't appear

Answer (score 1):

Library Developers already work on this, but the solution it's still on PR: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/pull/2562.

The solution is pretty simple actually, you only need to add an if and replace the Section elementName to Container. In my case, i'm using TemplateProccessor class so i just copy the PR code, create my custom TemplateProcessor class and override the setComplexBlock function, this is a temporary solution until the PR merge after that you should avoid modify directly the library code.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractElement;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\XMLWriter;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor as PHPWordTemplateProcessor;

 class TemplateProcessor extends PHPWordTemplateProcessor
 {

   public function setComplexBlock($search, AbstractElement $complexType): void
   {
    $elementName = substr(get_class($complexType), strrpos(get_class($complexType), '\\') + 1);
    
    //This is the solution
    if ($elementName === 'Section') {
        $elementName = 'Container';
    }
    $objectClass = 'PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Writer\\Word2007\\Element\\' . $elementName;

    $xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
    /** @var \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\AbstractElement $elementWriter */
    $elementWriter = new $objectClass($xmlWriter, $complexType, false);
    $elementWriter->write();

    $this->replaceXmlBlock($search, $xmlWriter->getData(), 'w:p');
 }
}
```

Comment: Excellent first answer, good job!