PHPWord replace placholder with html
So I have in my word document a placeholder: {{ test }}. I want to replace this placeholder with some html. But I can't seem to get it working an I do not know why.
This is the error that I'm getting:
Class \"PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Writer\\Word2007\\Element\\Section\" not found
And this is my code:
/**
     * @throws CopyFileException
     * @throws CreateTemporaryFileException
     */
    public static function replacePlaceholdersInDoc()
    {
        App::setFacadeApplication(app());

        // Load the document content from storage
        $fileContent = Storage::disk('public')->get('test.docx');

        // Create a temporary file and write the document content to it
        $tempFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'template');
        file_put_contents($tempFilePath, $fileContent);

        // Load the template processor with the temporary file
        $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($tempFilePath);
        $templateProcessor->setMacroChars('{{ ', ' }}');

        // Define the HTML placeholder content
        $htmlPlaceholder = '<p>Okay dit is een test, waarom is dit een test? Dit zijn de redenen waarom het een test is:</p><p>nummer 1:</p><p>Kaas</p><p>nummer 2:</p><p>kaas</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Nu in een mooie lijst</p><ul><li>Kaas</li><li>Kaas</li></ul><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Nu in een lijst met nummers:</p><ol><li>Kaas</li><li>Kaas</li></ol><p>&nbsp;</p><h2>Dit is een titel?</h2>';

        // Create a new PhpWord object and section
        $phpWord = new PhpWord();
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        Html::addHtml($section, $htmlPlaceholder);

        // Save the new PhpWord object to a temporary file
        $newTempFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'new_word');
        $phpWordWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $phpWordWriter->save($newTempFilePath);

        // Replace the placeholder in the template with the new content
        $templateProcessor->setComplexValue('test', $phpWord->getSections()[0]);

        // Save the modified template to a new temporary file
        $modifiedTempFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'modified_template');
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($modifiedTempFilePath);

        // Load the modified file content and save it back to storage
        $modifiedFileContent = file_get_contents($modifiedTempFilePath);
        Storage::disk('public')->put('modified_test.docx', $modifiedFileContent);

        // Clean up the temporary files
        unlink($tempFilePath);
        unlink($newTempFilePath);
        unlink($modifiedTempFilePath);

        return true;
    }


It seems to be the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455070/class-phpoffice-phpword-writer-word2007-element-section-not-found

Does this answer your question? Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\Section' not found
